# Simplest way for remote power control?

Tags: power, switches, wireless

I don't know much electronics (I'm a software engineer). I want to build or buy a remote power control, controlling over SMS or IP. 
I don't care if I need to implement my own API or do my own electronics.

Where can I find some resources for that? I found:

- iBoot: too expensive
- X10: I don't understand the difference between [3 pin appliance to the wall switch](http://www.x10.com/catalog/home_automation.html?TWENTY11) and i dont know if they are the cheapest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X10 is a good, reasonably inexpensive choice, whose standard has been around for a while, and thus has significant documentation and hobbyist examples available on the Internet.

For X10 projects/tutorials, you may want to start with [this Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-up-basic-x10-for-newbies/) as well as [this one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-home-automation-and-security-using-x10/).

Also, to learn more options, you may consider reading the book [Smart Homes For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470165677), which provides background on a variety of options including X10, although this book is short on details for practical implementation.

That said, if you want to step the DIY aspect up a notch, you may want to invest your time learning to use an inexpensive hobbyist microcontroller board such as [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction), and supplement it with some basic experiments with [AC Relays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Applications). Then your options will really open up, including allowing wireless control networks, as well as power-on/offs triggered by sensor readings, status indicators, etc., limited by your creativity/requirements.

Comment: Can you give a link to concrete  AC Relay to use with Arduino?

Comment: I suggest you start with [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10747), safe, pre-assembled, and very easy to use. There are also a number of tutorials on that device, for example [this one](http://techvalleyprojects.blogspot.com/2012/04/powerswitch-tail-ii-and-arduino.html). IIRC, the creator of PowerSwitchTail also included a circuit diagram, along with parts list, on [its datasheet](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Documents/PST%20II%20product%20insert,%20Aug%202012.pdf) available on their website -- So you could conceivably use that if you want to build one yourself for cheaper.

Comment: Sorry, last question - all devices that i see are 110V in my country we work with 220V, should i also buy a converter or there are also 220V available?

Comment: The [website](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/PSTIIU.aspx) of that device clearly lists that they have a 200-240 VAC option.

Answer (score 1):

I have an interface that works with any of the sms enabled devices. I have tested the Arduino and I'm currently running a three phase 220v switch in production solution. Have a look at the [demo](http://synapcontrol.com/Demonstration/tabid/163/Default.aspx).